# Distance traveled during changing acceleration (calculus-based physics)

Tags: calculus, physics, kinematics

> The acceleration as a function of time $a(t)$ (in m/s$^2$) and the initial velocity $v(0)$ are given for a particle moving along a line:
>   $$a(t) = 2t + 4, \hspace{4mm}v(0) = −5, \hspace{8mm} 0 \leq  t \leq 4.$$
>   (a) Find the velocity at time $t$. ($v(t) =  t^2+4t−5$)
>
> (b) Find the distance traveled during the given time interval.

I was able to solve part (a) but have been having issues with part (b). It's a webassign assignment and the "master it" section only gives me the first portion and it hasn't allowed me to see other problems so I could try and figure it out by example. Is anyone able to explain to me how to do this?

Comment: For part (b), what have you tried so far? It may be helpful to find the position $x(t)$ as a function of time, and sketch the corresponding graph to see the motion. (Actually, sketching $v(t)$ as a function of time may be more useful: Is the particle moving in the same direction at all times?)

Comment: I haven't tried anything because I didn't know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

You have an expression for the velocity.

To calculate **distance** as opposed to displacement, you need to know the time(s) when $v=0$, since the particle reverses the direction of motion at these times, and integrate the velocity separately over these time intervals, taking the absolute value where necessary.

Clearly $v=0\Rightarrow t=1$

Therefore the distance travelled is $$\left|\int_0^1(t^2+4t-5)dt\right|+\left|\int_1^4(t^2+4t-5)dt\right|$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The initial velocity is $v(0)=-5$ m/s, whereas from part (a) the final velocity is $v(4) = +27$ m/s. So the particle evidently moves to the left, comes to rest at some time $T$, and then moves back to the right until time $t=4$. How far does it move to the left by time $T$, and how far does it move to the right in the time remaining?

Comment: still kind of confused, sorry I'm not the best at calculus. I'm just not sure what I am so supposed to do as far as do I need to subtract or add something or if there is a formula to use. I'm a visual learner so I usually see other examples first and follow it.

Comment: I can't give an example off the top of my head. For a visual, though, try plotting the velocity $v(t)=t^2+4t-5$ as a function of time $t$ and use that to make a rough sketch of the position as a function of time. You shouldn't need calculus for that so much as just some physics-thinking. (You could also try plotting $a(t)=2t+4$ and seeing how that relates graphically to the plot of $v(t)$.)